# Is there a way to break out of list comprehension?

Tags: python

When using infinite generators, I can use `if` to prevent items from entering the list, but not in order to break the loop.

This will actually crash and hang. Not even `KeyboardInterrupt` can save me (why is that BTW?)

```
import itertools
a = [x for x in itertools.count() if x<10]
```

While if I use my own infinite generator

```
def mygen():
    i=0
    while True:
        yield i
        i +=1
```

this will run until `KeyboardInterrupt`

```
a = [x for x in mygen() if x<10]
```

Now, obviously for a proper `for` loop we can break when a condition is met

```
a = []
for x in itertools.count():
    a.append(x)
    if x>9:
        break
```

So my question: Is there some way to break out of list comprehension?

Comment: List comprehensions are not *clairvoyant*. `[x for x in itertools.count() if x<10]` will attempt to run through all the items in the `count` object and only return those less than `10`. It goes on and on. . .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `itertools.takewhile` to cease iteration after a condition is no longer met...:

```
import itertools

a = [x for x in itertools.takewhile(lambda L: L < 10, itertools.count())]
# a = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda L: < 10, itertools.count()))
```

There's isn't per-se a way to break out of a list-comp, so limiting the iterable (`takewhile` or `islice` etc... is the way to go...)